# How do I put a new installed program on the dock?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, installed-programs

I installed a new program but I can't find it. I want to put a shortcut on the dock. So how do I find the icon for the new program?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, and what desktop environment?

Comment: The latest Ubuntu. I don't know how to find the version but that should be on the internet. I'm not sure what you mean by "desktop environment"... all I know it is the one that comes with Ubuntu.

Comment: Linux eddys-ubuntu 4.18.0-15-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 10:56:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @j-money why do you think `uname -a` would be useful here? It doesn't show which flavor is in use...

Comment: @j-money ... can't you tell that I'm new at Linux? What gave you clue that I knew what I was doing? Comments like yours are far from productive.

Answer (score 1):

Click the box of dots at the lower left. Then use the search option to find the new program. Then right click and select Add to Favorites. But sometimes the program just shows small icons. In that case there is no right click option ... I don't know what to do about that. An example is "Wine".